# Lua - Corona SDK - Text not appearing inside a display Object

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to move a display object that is hiding over the right side of the screen, into the scene. It works wonderfully with images (i.e. the background), but not with texts (the coords seem correct from debugging them with print(), but they never display, I already tried the obj:toFront).
I thought that they may work inside display objects, so I put everything in a display Object: Nothing. Just the text? Neither. Anyone knows why/how to override this?

```
 function tscreen:init()
    local textGroup = display.newGroup()

    local menuBackground = self:getBtn("src/bgMenu.png")
    menuBackground.isVisible = false
    menuBackground.anchorX = 0.5
    menuBackground.anchorY = 0.5
    self.menuBackground = menuBackground

    local optionsText = {
        parent = textGroup,
        text = "Hello World",     
        x = centerX,
        y = centerY,
        width = 128,     
        font = native.systemFontBold,   
        fontSize = 14,
        align = "center" 
    }
    local workText = display.newText( optionsText )
    workText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
    setPos(textGroup, W, 0) 
            --setPos() is a custom function that assigns x and y coords
    textGroup.isVisible = false

    self.textGroup = textGroup
  end

 function tscreen:show()
    local menuBackground = self.menuBackground
    local textGroup      = self.textGroup

    local inTime        = 1200

    setPos(menuBackground, 2*W + centerX, centerY)
    menuBackground.isVisible = true

    setPos(textGroup, W, 0)
    textGroup.isVisible = true

    self:cancelTween(menuBackground)
    self:cancelTween(textGroup)

    menuBackground.tween = transition.to(menuBackground, {time = inTime, transition = easing.outExpo, x = centerX,
        onComplete = function()
        tscreen:cancelTween(menuBackground)
    end
    })

    textGroup.tween = transition.to(textGroup, {time = inTime, transition = easing.outExpo, x = 0,
        onComplete = function()
        tscreen:cancelTween(textGroup)
        print(getPos(textGroup), textGroup.width, textGroup.height)
    end
    })

end
```

I have the starters edition of Corona, so I don't have the recently implemented Composer API.
Maybe this isn't the most appropriate site to post this query since there already is a Corona SDK forum, but I'm trying anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything wrong, but a group should not be necessary. Verify that the text *can* be seen ever: in the init(), do

```
local optionsText = {
    text = "Hello World",     
    x = 0,
    y = 100,
}
local workText = display.newText( optionsText )
workText:setFillColor( 1, 1, 1 )
```

If you can't see the text then something else is going on, maybe your init() is not being called or such. Once you see it, change the parameters to what you want (fill color etc), and test. If still works, add a transition, right after, in the init():

```
local easeXto100 = {
     time = 2000, 
     transition = easing.outExpo, 
     x = 100,
     onComplete = function() print('did you see text move from x=0 to 100?') end
}
transition.to(workText, easeXto100)
```

If you see it move, then move the relevant parts of code to your show(), if now it disappears this will give you clue.

Comment: I tested and tested, and at the end I figured a workaround! I was using a function "getBtn" to generate the image of the background, so I made another  function for the text that simply made the text work as a button. Thanks for.. telling me not to give up (that sounded cheesy)!

Comment: Great glad you cracked the problem. So what does that new function doing that fixes it?

Comment: This is the function I used for the btn http://pastebin.com/r4xaEg7R and the new function is this http://pastebin.com/rczXtXGJ